# python regex two words separated

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex: `^[ ]{0,1}[^\s]+$` who matches only one word, for example: *Silver* or *min*. I want to add another word space separated. For example: `Silver silver` or `1 min` should be a match as well.

Comment: Do you mean you need to match a string having 1 or 2 non-whitespace chunks with leading/trailing whitespace support? Like `^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+)?\s*$`?

Comment: Can your question be summarized with *I want to match a pattern and the next and previous space-separated word, if they exist*?

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^[^\s]+(?: [^\s]+)?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI8mZH/1)

Answer (score 0):

For your example data you might also use [`\w+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) to match one or more times a word character. Using `[^\s]+` or `\S+` matches one or more times a non-whitespace character which would be a much broader range.

Your regex starts with `[ ]{0,1}` which matches a whitespace zero or one time which makes it optional. Keeping the whitespace at the start and using a questionmark to make it optional, you could add an optional grouping structure `(?:[ ]\w+)?` which would match a whitespace followed by matching one or more times a word character.

Your regex could look like:

`^[ ]?\w+(?:[ ]\w+)?$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mLuBRn/1)